# tdstats.UDFCONCAT parameter varchar limit

Tags: teradata

I was using `tdstats.UDFCONCAT` to aggregate result of the query,

This function trims the resulting output, upon looked at the definition of this function, it accepts `VARCHAR(128)` .

`REPLACE FUNCTION tdstats.UDFCONCAT 
  (aVarchar VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET UNICODE) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE 
 CLASS AGGREGATE (20000)
 SPECIFIC udfConcat 
 LANGUAGE C 
 NO SQL
 NO EXTERNAL DATA
 PARAMETER STYLE SQL 
 NOT DETERMINISTIC 
 CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
 EXTERNAL NAME 'SL!staudf!F!udf_concatvarchar'`

Can anybody tell if there is any specific reason to keep it limited to `128`?

Note: I have duplicated the function and increased the size from `128` to `256` and it worked in my case. If anybody wants to know my use case then I can update here but question is regarding the default character limit mentioned by TD in the in-built function, so have not added my use case here.

Comment: `UDFConcat` is an undocumented function, but the length of 128 is related to it's functionality, creating a comma delimited list of column names. Good to know that the default length can be increased :-)

Comment: ok, so I am good here :-)